# Downloading from a website Android

Tags: android, webview, download

The Url of my path is something like this `www.sample.com/sample/1234`.
When you click on the path it downloads a file something like this

```
Sample_hello_sample.epub
```

I couldn't make my app work with this download.

Here's my code:

```
private class InsideWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.contains("sample")) {
            startDownload(url);
            return true;
        }

        //...?

        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
               .setCancelable(false)
               .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       Gutenbergmain.this.finish();
                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                   }
               });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    private void startDownload(String url) {
        new DownloadFileAsync().execute(url);
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS:
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading file..");
            mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();
            return mProgressDialog;

        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog, Bundle args) {
        if (id == DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS)
            mProgressDialog.setProgress(0);
    }

    class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
            mProgressDialog.setProgress(0);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
            int count;

            try {
                URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);

                URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
                conexion.connect();

                int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
                Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);

                String path = url.getPath();
                String idStr = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

                String fileName = idStr;

                File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/Sample/epub");
                dir.mkdirs();

                File file = new File(dir, fileName);

                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);

                //InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                //OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/" + fileName);

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
                    f.write(data, 0, count);
                    //output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                f.flush();
                f.close();

                //output.flush();
                //output.close();

                input.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {}

            return null;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
             Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC",progress[0]);
             mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
            dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must edit your AndroidManifest.xml file. for example.

```
<intent-filter >
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <data android:mimeType="application/*"  />
   <data android:host="*" /> 
   <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.epub" /> 
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: The filename downloaded from the website is equal to (1234) that is from this address www.sample.com/sample/1234 and not Sample_hello_sample.epub .I think there is some modification needed on this line below String path = url.getPath(); .Thanks John

Comment: I understand now sorry. I would belive you might like to lookinto mimeType on server and your application but i am doing an educated guess but a guess non the less.